# How to use circuitikz command inside latex new command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, circuitikz

I want to make a new command in circuitikz which creates a bus line with an arrow at the end. The code is the following:

```
\newcommand{\busLineWithArrow}[3]{\draw (#1) \to[multiwire=#3] (#2) [arrow];}

\begin{circuitikz}
    
    % defined nodes named point A and B in this region

    \busLineWithArrow{pointA}{pointB}{64}
\end{circuitikz}
```

The error I get in overleaf is:

*Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.*

The problem exists with `\to[multiwire=#3]` command, when I replace it with `--` I see a line with an arrow at the end fine.

Comment: Mmhh. First of all, it's `to`, no `\to` (without backslash). Then, I have the suspicion you are misusing `[arrow]`; that is a path specifier, not "position an arrow here", and will act strange with the circuitikz path elements. Too late to switch on my PC to answer now, if no one answer I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: BTW, Welcome; and please, always post complete code, not just snippets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for. The main mistake was the backslash before `to` and the misunderstanding about how arrows work in Ti*k*Z.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\busLineWithArrow}[3]{\draw (#1) to[multiwire=#3] (#2) node[inputarrow]{};}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    % defined nodes named point A and B in this region
    \coordinate (pointA) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pointB) at(3,0);

    \busLineWithArrow{pointA}{pointB}{64}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Please also notice that this is a minimal, complete example that can be compiled, and the preferred way to ask questions here).

Finally, about the comment regarding arrows, look at this snippet (commented!) and at the Ti*k*Z manual https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf./pgf/tips :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % arrow is a path global thing, and it's applied only to the
    % last subpath!
    \draw (0,2) -- ++(1,0) ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0) [<-];
    % it doesn't matter where you put the arrow option...
    \draw [<-] (0,1) -- ++(1,0) ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0);
    % so... this could surprise you
    \draw [<-] (0,0) to[R] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, should I edit the code in my question?

Comment: No, otherwise the answer lose meaning! Thanks,